# how to set for-loop times limit and break the for-loop?

Tags: matlab, for-loop

I would type the number 1~22. (because the number of figure is 22.)

( ex) when i type 1 then figure(1) is shown up. )

now i want to set times limit of this loop to 22.

because even i type all of them, they can't over 22.

and also i want to know the way end this loop without typing all number (less than 22).

i will show the code that i writed, please give me the advice.

```
for TNP=1:23     
**% for-loop's end condition -->1. when i type all 22 number. 
                        ->2. when i type 23 to end the for-loop without typing more number.**

   FN = input('Which figure do you want: ')   **% here i would type the number of figure.**

  if FN==1
   F1=meshc(z(:,111:268))
   grid on
   hold on

  elseif FN==2
   F2=meshc(z(:,269:419))
   grid on
   hold on

  elseif FN==3
   F3=meshc(z(:,431:586))
   grid on
   hold on
. 
. 
.
  else FN=23
   close;
  end

end   
**% but even i add the 'break' for-loop doesn't end. what is the reason??**
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use a loop here.

A loop is used when you want to repeat some code an specific number of times, which is not the case here (if I understood correctly).

What you want is to accept inputs from 1 to 22 to show the corresponding figures. I assume the figures don't have to be in order (otherwise you won't need a manual input)

You have to first define a number that will finish the loop (for example -1) and then use a while.

```
FN = input('Which figure do you want (1 to 22, or -1 to exit)?: ')
while FN ~= -1
    if FN < 1 | FN > 22
        disp (['Incorrect option: ' num2str(FN)]);
    else
        % your code to handle correct cases here
    end
    % now ask again
    FN = input('Which figure do you want (1 to 22, or -1 to exit)?: ')
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with SembeiNorimaki -- your chosen design is a bit strange. I would go for something similar to what s/he wrote:

```
function myfcn()

    % (define Z here)

    % User input loop        
    while true

        % Get the number
        FN = input('Which figure do you want: ');            

        % Don't ever trust the user, even if 
        % the only user is you
        if ~isnumeric(FN) || ...
                ~isscalar(FN) || ....
                ~isfinite(FN) || ...
                ~isreal(FN) || ...
                FN > 23 || ...
                FN < 0

            warning([mfilename ':invalid_input'],...
                    'Invalid input; please insert a figure number 1-23, or 0 to exit.');
            continue;

        end

        % It's always good to have an explicit exit condition
        if FN == 0
            break; end

        % Apparently, you want this to be a special case
        % (Note that this will only close the last figure drawn)
        if FN == 23
            close; end

        % Call a handler to do all the heavy lifting
        h = myGraphicsHandler(z, round(FN));

        % ...Do whatever you want with this handle

    end

end

function h = myGraphicsHandler(z, FN)

    % These are the only things that seem to be 
    % different between each case
    rangesTable = {111:268
                   269:419
                   431:586  % ... and so on
                  };

    % create the figure
    h = figure;
    hold on
    meshc(z(:, rangesTable{FN}));
    grid on    

    % ... other operations / figure decorations here

end
```